Route pulseaudio to more than 2 devices
I have a gstreamer pipeline that tee's audio into multiple sinks (devices). I've a bunch of sinks I want to route the audio to but it doesn't seem to work. When I tee the pipeline to max 2 devices, there is audio through the devices. It can be any 2 of the many sinks I've set up, the audio works. But when I try to tee it to a 3rd device, there's no audio anywhere. I've confirmed that all the devices (sinks) work on their own or with just another sink. But not when it is more than 2.
I set up the sinks in the following manner
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3 sink_name=hdmi
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:1,0 sink_name=usb

And I'm using it in my gstreamer like this
        out_sink_hdmi = gst_element_factory_make ("pulsesink", "out_sink_hdmi");
        g_assert_nonnull (out_sink_hdmi);
        g_object_set (out_sink_hdmi, "device", "hdmi", NULL);

        out_sink_usb = gst_element_factory_make ("pulsesink", "out_sink_usb");
        g_assert_nonnull (out_sink_usb);
        g_object_set (out_sink_usb, "device", "usb", NULL);

What's blocking the audio from getting routed to other devices sinks? I'm running pulseaudio in system mode and have not made any changes to the system.pa file.
